# Filter one column and count values in other

Tags: excel, database, vba

I have a database where is in column C the names of tools like: `KDX15`, `GUA10`, `PKN01` and they are repeated in this column many times but they have added value each time in column D.

Example:

```
  C   |   D
KDX15 | 15000
GUA10 |  2000
PKN01 |  2000
KDX15 |   100
KDX15 |   100
GUA10 |  2530
```

I want to filter this values to different sheet but have filtered every name example. `KDX15` and summary from column D `15200`

How can I do this? 
So far I was able to create a macro for filter of the column C

```
Sheets("NEUPRAVOVAT").Columns("C:C").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H1"), Unique:=True
```

I just want to see filtered values of column C  with summary of each value from column D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use a Pivot Table …

… to get the following result:

[image]

---

#### How to create it

Imagine the following data

[image]

1. Select the data
2. From ribbon menu select: Insert › Pivot Table
3. In the following  dialog select where you want to insert the pivot table (and press OK)

   [image]
4. Check the marked boxes
   [image]
5. Done

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful and easy to done last thing I done was auto refresh code for data sheet to get live update of datas                                                         `Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range) 

    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub`      Now its all working and ready to go :) thank you very much